# How to stub a super() call with Sinon

Tags: coffeescript, sinon

I am using Coffeescript and I'm testing using Sinon.js. When testing a method that invokes the method it overwrites, how can I stub the call to `super()`?

E.g., the method I want to test (a backbone.js model):

```
class Whatever extends Model
  validate: (attributes) ->
    validationErrors = super(attributes)
    ...
    validationErrors
```

In the example, I want to make sure that `super()` is invoked with the given attributes and that validate returns the validation errors `super()` returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
it 'calls super and returns its result', ->
  whatever = new Whatever()
  attributes = sinon.stub()
  superValidateStub = sinon.mock(Whatever.__super__)
  superValidateStub.expects('validate').withExactArgs(attributes).returns('VALIDATION_RESULT')

  expect(whatever.validate(attributes)).to.eql('VALIDATION_RESULT')

  superValidateStub.verify()
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Shouldn’t you first mock and then construct?

Comment: @AdrianLang: not necessary in this case because `__super__` is a property of the `Whatever` constructor, not its prototype. A `super` statement inside `Whatever.validate` gets translated to `Whatever.__super__.validate()`.